# Counter in Flash and Tweener as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays, loops

My scrolling counter is not displaying 1-9...only “zeros” every ten intervals. It plays, but the code is unfinished at line 37 in NumbersView.as. Notice Tweener is used to display the sprites. How do I finish this?

**WHAT I'M TESTING** "NumbersView.as"
loop error, onComplete, missing argument or function
- Tweener code, line 37?
- for loop, line 22? for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++)

Thanks for the help!

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note3.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note3.jpg)

**numbers.fla**

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note1.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note1.jpg)
[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note2.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/note2.jpg)

**NumbersView.as** "see Tweener part towards the bottom"

```
package  
{
 import flash.display.DisplayObject;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.utils.Dictionary;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import caurina.transitions.Tweener;


 public class NumbersView extends MovieClip
 {

  private var _listItems:Array = new Array();


  public function NumbersView() 
  {
   var item:NumberImage;
   for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    item = new NumberImage();
    addChild(item);
    item.x = i * item.width;
    _listItems.push(item);
   }

  }


  public function setTime($number:String):void {
   var nums:Array = $number.split("");
   for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (int(nums[i]) == 0) {
     Tweener.removeTweens(_listItems[i].moveableNumber_mc);
     if (_listItems[i].moveableNumber_mc.y < 0) {
      _listItems[i].moveableNumber_mc.y = 120;
     }
     Tweener.addTween(_listItems[i].moveableNumber_mc, { y: 0, time:.3 } );
    } else {
     Tweener.addTween(_listItems[i].moveableNumber_mc, { y: -120 * int(nums[i]), time:.3} );
    }
   }
  }
 }

}
```

**NumberDocumentClass.as** "works fine"

```
package {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.utils.Timer;
 import flash.events.TimerEvent;

 public class NumberDocumentClass extends Sprite {

  private var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);
  private var count:int = 0;
  private var fcount:int = 0;
  private var numbers:NumbersView;

  public function NumberDocumentClass() {
   timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);    
   timer.start();   
   numbers = new NumbersView();
   addChild(numbers);
  }

  function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {    
   count++;    
   fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up   
   numbers.setTime(formatCount(fcount));
  }  

  function formatCount(i:int):String {   
   return ("000000000" + i).substr(-9, 9); 
  } 
 }
}
```

I got it debugged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few things in your code, so I edited it and it works fine.

The main problem is that you Flash library item (mc-NumberImage) wasn't set up for the way you were using it. You put the number graphics on frames, so I modified it so the movieclip has one frame with all the numbers on top of each other. So **number_0.y = 0**, and **number_1.y = 120**... **number_2.y = 240**, etc. (also In your library your "number_8.jpg" is actually a number 7).

If you just make that change then your code runs *OK*. It does get slower and slower though. This is partly due to Tweener, but mostly because it is trying to update too much. I updated you code below.

### NumberDocumentClass

Separated out the *incrementCounter*, and the display code. So now *numbers.setTime()* gets called on *enterframe* (no point drawing more than once a frame, Flash can't do it). I also initiated your Timer in the constructor rather than in the variable declaration (this is best practice).

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class NumberDocumentClass extends Sprite {

        private var timer:Timer;
        private var count:int = 0;
        private var fcount:int = 0;
        private var numbers:NumbersView;

        public function NumberDocumentClass() {
            timer = new Timer(10);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);    
            timer.start();   
            numbers = new NumbersView();
            addChild(numbers);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        private function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {    
            count++;    
            fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up
        }

        private function formatCount(i:int):String {   
            return ("000000000" + i).substr(-9, 9);
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void 
        {
            numbers.setTime(formatCount(fcount));
        }
    }
}
```

### NumberView

I mainly edited the setTime method. I added a previousNums variable that remembers the previous numbers, that way we can use it to see if a number has changed, and if it hasn't then you can skip it (*if(nums[i] == previousNums[i]) continue;*).

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

    public class NumbersView extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _listItems:Array;
        private var previousNums:Array;
        private const numHeight:int = 120;

        public function NumbersView() 
        {
            _listItems = new Array();
            previousNums = new Array();

            var item:NumberImage;
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                item = new NumberImage();
                addChild(item);
                item.x = i * item.width;
                _listItems.push(item);
            }
        }

        public function setTime($number:String):void {
            var nums:Array = $number.split("");

            for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if (nums[i] == previousNums[i]) continue;
                Tweener.removeTweens(_listItems[i]);

                var newY:int = int(nums[i]) * -numHeight;
                if (_listItems[i].y < 0) _listItems[i].y = numHeight;
                Tweener.addTween(_listItems[i], { y:newY, time:.1 } );
            }
            previousNums = nums;
        }
    }
}
```

So if you set up your FLA with the number graphics aligned vertically, and you use this code, then it should run really well.