# "lost in strings" AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can someone follow what doing, and show me how to do it correctly? I'm new with strings and arrays. Anything you can suggest would be appreciated.

**GOAL**
I want script to calling display objects to the stage, and the timer to move images up and down to appear like a scrolling numbers. I start getting sloppy, and mess up passing to Tweener.

**THOUGHTS**
 
- An explanation or strategy may be enough, "I've got pretty close on this one"
- *There was confusion regarding the Containers and addChildren...looked like arrays*

**THE CODE** "get as far as error with NumbersView and numbers undefined etc"

```
 //-------------------------IMPORT METHODS---------------------------------------
        import flash.display.DisplayObject; 
        import flash.display.MovieClip; 
        import flash.utils.Dictionary; 
        import flash.events.Event; 
        import caurina.transitions.Tweener; 

//-----------------------TIMER---------------------------------------       
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);//
    //var timer:Timer;  
    var count:int = 0; 
    var fcount:int = 0; 
    var _listItems:Array = new Array();
    var previousNums:Array;
    const numHeight:int = 120;
    //var numbers:NumbersView;
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
    timer.start(); 

//-----------------------COUNTER-CONT-----------------------
    function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
      count++;  
      fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
    //  mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);
    NumbersView(1);
    //}

//----------------------ZERO PLACE HOLDERS-----------------------
    }
    function formatCount(i:int):String { 
         var fraction:int = i % 100; 
         var whole:int = i / 100;  
      return ("000000000" + i).substr(-9, 9); 
       // return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
    } 

    //

//----------------------DISPLAY for loop, integer to string "puts numbers on stage"
    function NumbersView($n:int):void {
     //function NumbersView()//
     //{
        _listItems = new Array();
        previousNums = new Array();
        var item:NumberImage;
        var offset:int = _listItems.length;
        //for (var i:int = 0; i < $n; i++)
     for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
           item = new NumberImage();
           //item.x = (i + offset) * 9;
           //item.y = (i + offset) * 9;
        item.x = i * item.width; 
           _listItems.push(item); 
           addChild(item);
        }

//----------------------SPLIT STRING "pass to Tweener or some other method"---------------
    //
       function setTime($number:String):void { 
                var nums:Array = $number.split(""); 
                for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
                if (nums[i] == NumbersView[i]) continue; 
                Tweener.removeTweens(NumbersView[i]); 
       }
```

The methods were proved separately. "I got a earlier version of the
document going, but I need to work through this to understand it."

**SYMBOL PROPERTIES**
CLASS ImageView

**TWEENER**
The "caurina" folder needs to be present

**ROLLING NUMBERS** "SUCCESS loading numbers and connecting to counter"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**What I did for Debu's example**
Placed the movie clip object on stage with two dynamic text fields in it.
**Note**
Make sure the container is placed on stage, has the two text fileds in it, and everything is given a proper instance name. Also include the caurina folder.

**seconds** MovieClip symbol with instance name of seconds 
**firstDigit** Dynamic text field with instance name of firstDigit, placed in seconds
**secondDigit** Dynamic text field with instance name of secondDigit, placed in seconds

**Symbol**
Un-tick 'Export for ActionScript'
Use 'Name, Class, and Instance' correctly

Comment: Hmm.. I understand what you're trying to do, but your code is really confusing, perhaps you should go through and comment what each line is doing and edit this post? Also, you seem to quote yourself in your questions.. what's the deal there? That's just pure curiosity.

Comment: See Comments. ""doesn't get confused with code and it's emphatic

Comment: This site has formatting, which you make good use of, to make sure code is separated from prose. Emphatic is one way to describe quoting yourself; plain-odd would be another, I certainly find it jarring to read.

The comments aren't really going deep enough, I'd need to see the functions commented in more detail. Did you write the code or is it an example you're trying to figure out?

Comment: Here's where it originated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290737/counter-in-flash-and-tweener-as3

Comment: An expert told me to put it in one document to make it easier. I am jarring and odd in real life. I want to get back to killing enemy frogs, but this projects killing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a very simple example of what I believe you're trying to do. It only contains one digit, the seconds, and simply counts up to 9, then back to 0 and up to 9 again. Each time the Timer object I've created is fired (every 1000ms, or 1s) it runs a function which tweens in the new digit. I've pasted the code below, and commented each line; let me know if you don't understand any of it.

```
import caurina.transitions.*;

//Create a timer that will run for 1 second, and repeat
var secondTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

//A counter for seconds
var secondsCount:int = 0;

//The original position of the rolling numbers object on the stage
var originalYPosition:Number = 0;
//The position of the rolling numbers object on stage when it's displaying its second digit
var upwardYPosition:Number = -127;
//The speed you want the odometer to roll at. As this is the seconds counter it needs to be less than 1
var rollSpeed:Number = 0.25; //seconds

//Start the timer
secondTimer.start();
//Add an event listener to fire each time it reaches its limit
secondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateOdometer);

//Add a generic update loop, to test for when the odometer has been moved to its 'up' position
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkOdometerPosition);

function updateOdometer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //When the timer fires, check if secondsCount is less than 9; if it is, increment secondsCount
    if (secondsCount < 9)
    {
        secondsCount++;
    }
    else 
    {
        //Otherwise set secondsCount to 0, so the odometer will loop from 9 back to 0
        secondsCount = 0;
    }

    //Set the text inside seconds > secondDigit equal to the next digit it needs to display.
    seconds.secondDigit.text = secondsCount.toString();

    //Do the tween, so that the secondDigit changed above will become visible
    Tweener.addTween(seconds, { y: upwardYPosition, time: rollSpeed, transition:"easeOutQuad" } );
}

//This function runs all the time, to check when the rolling object has moved upwards
function checkOdometerPosition(event:Event):void
{
    //Do the check to see if it's in its upward position..
    if (seconds.y <= upwardYPosition)
    {
        //If it is, make the first digit equal to the current second digit
        seconds.firstDigit.text = secondsCount.toString();
        //Then move the odometer back into its original position..
        seconds.y = originalYPosition;

        //This is so that the odometer is ready to be moved upwards again when the timer fires again.
    }
}
```

All this code requires is a simple MovieClip object on the stage with two dynamic TextFields inside it; one placed exactly below the other. I've named the containing object 'seconds', the top-most TextField 'firstDigit', and the bottom TextField 'secondDigit'. Re-create this inside a Flash document, save it (making sure carina is in the same folder), paste the code in on frame 1, and it should work fine. *Edit: I created an image to illustrate how the objects should be structured inside your .fla:*

[image]

Oh, and as for that expert who told you to quote yourself, he doesn't sound like such an expert to me ;) Anyway, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm on some little laptop half seeing what I'm doing, but think I follow. I updated my post with a link to the file. I get a 1046: Type was not found error. What did I do? ...maybe I used "quotes"
in the properties panel. :)

Comment: Ok, that's an easy fix. You need to un-tick 'Export for ActionScript', in the properties of the 'seconds' object in your library. 

I think you've miss-understood what Export for ActionScript does. When you tick that box, the name you put in 'Class' associates that object with a new object type, named whatever you put in that box. Generally you only need to do this if you're then going to write an external .AS file, which gives that specific object new behaviour. In this case we're just using MovieClips, so it's unnecessary, and was causing the error.

Comment: Also, the error you were getting was because you didn't begin the name of that Class (in properties of 'seconds') with a capital S. Classes need a capital at the beginning. I hope that helps explain what Export for ActionScript does, and also solves the problem you had in this overall question.

Comment: Haha, I just got your quotes joke ;) Bravo

Comment: Thanks for explaining. My properties panel make more sense now, and the numbers look great.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it's working and you've got a clearer understanding of classes and objects.